# How to draw Pivot points using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm using plotly to draw some chart with SMA and MACD data. This works fine.

```
fig = make_subplots(vertical_spacing = 0, rows=3, cols=1, row_heights=[0.6, 0.2, 0.2])

fig.add_trace(go.Ohlc(x=data['timestamp'],
            open=data['open'],
            high=data['high'],
            low=data['low'],
            close=data['close']))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['timestamp'], y=data['sma'], line=dict(color='orange', width=1)), row=1, col=1)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['timestamp'], y = data['macd']), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['timestamp'], y = data['macds']*1.1), row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=data['timestamp'], y = data['volume']), row=3, col=1)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,
                xaxis=dict(zerolinecolor='black', showticklabels=False),
                xaxis2=dict(showticklabels=False))

fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=False)
fig.show()
```

But now I want to add pivots:

```
    last_day['Pivot'] = (last_day['High'] + last_day['Low'] + last_day['Close'])/3
    last_day['R1'] = 2*last_day['Pivot'] - last_day['Low']
    last_day['S1'] = 2*last_day['Pivot'] - last_day['High']
    last_day['R2'] = last_day['Pivot'] + (last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
    last_day['S2'] = last_day['Pivot'] - (last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
    last_day['R3'] = last_day['Pivot'] + 2*(last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
    last_day['S3'] = last_day['Pivot'] - 2*(last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
```

The output of last_day looks like this:

```
                    Timestamp      Open      High       Low     Close  Volume    Pivot        R1        S1        R2        S2        R3        S3
499  2020-10-11T14:45:00.000Z  0.000321  0.000321  0.000319  0.000319  886.17  0.00032  0.000321  0.000319  0.000322  0.000318  0.000323  0.000316
```

How can I add this data (Pivot, S1, S2, S3, ...) to my figure? I would want to have something comparable with the picture here: https://www.fxpivot-points.com/?page=4

[image]

I tried this:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=last_day['Timestamp'], y=last_day['Pivot'], line=dict(color='purple', width=1)), row=1, col=1)
```

But it only draws a dot since I provide only one timestamp. How can I make this a horizontal line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifically asking to plot calculated points for the *last* day only, and display them for your complete time period for which you have a candlestick chart. If that's in fact what you're aiming to achieve here, then the code snippet below will produce the following plot using, among other things, `fig.add_shapes()` and `fig.add_annotations()` to display horizontal lines and pivot point names, respectively.

Let me know if something is not quite right, and we can discuss further tweaks.

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code based on Apple sample data:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv').tail(5)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

last_day = df.iloc[-1].to_frame().T
last_day = last_day.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('AAPL.', ''))


not_pivots = list(last_day.columns)
last_day['Pivot'] = (last_day['High'] + last_day['Low'] + last_day['Close'])/3
last_day['R1'] = 2*last_day['Pivot'] - last_day['Low']
last_day['S1'] = 2*last_day['Pivot'] - last_day['High']
last_day['R2'] = last_day['Pivot'] + (last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
last_day['S2'] = last_day['Pivot'] - (last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
last_day['R3'] = last_day['Pivot'] + 2*(last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
last_day['S3'] = last_day['Pivot'] - 2*(last_day['High'] - last_day['Low'])
last_day

pivots = [n for n in last_day.columns if n not in not_pivots]

pcols = ['green', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'black', 'black']

for i, col in enumerate(pivots):

    # horizontal lines
    fig.add_shape(type="line",
                    x0=df['Date'].iloc[0],
                    y0=last_day[col].iloc[-1],
                    x1=df['Date'].iloc[-1],
                    y1=last_day[col].iloc[-1],
                    line=dict(
                        color=pcols[i],
                        width=1,
                        #dash="dashdot",
                    ),)
    
    # line annotations
    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color=pcols[i],size=12),
                                        x=df['Date'].iloc[0],
                                        y=last_day[col].iloc[0],
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text=col,
                                        textangle=0,
                                        xanchor='right',
                                        xref="x",
                                        yref="y"))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I know these calculations are only for the last day and the graph is showing multiple days!

Comment: @DenCowboy OK, cool! It just seemed a bit weird to me given the image in the linked source. But if that's what you want then that's what you'll get =)

Comment: I'm now using multiple das so I can check multiple macd crosses etc but in the end I will just print a graph of just one day :)